# Figuring out whether LL(1) grammar has an $\varepsilon$-free variant

Tags: formal-grammars

This question arose out of a concrete problem I had, which was to find an $\varepsilon$-free variant of the following LL(1) grammar $G_0$ that I developed for a Lisp-like language $L$ (I found a monotone LR(0) variant):

$$
\begin{array} \\
P & \rightarrow & (EP \\
  & | & \varepsilon \\
E & \rightarrow &iE \\
  & | &sE \\
  & | &nE \\
  & | &(EE \\
  & | &)
\end{array}
$$
where the start symbol is $P$. With this grammar, the leftmost derivation of $\omega = (i()sn)(inn)$ is
$$
\begin{array} \\
P & \Rightarrow_L (EP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (iEP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i(EEP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()EP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()sEP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()snEP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()sn)P \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()sn)(EP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()sn)(iEP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()sn)(inEP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()sn)(innEP \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()sn)(inn)P \\
  & \Rightarrow_L (i()sn)(inn)
\end{array}
$$
My problem is that the parser generated by this grammar accepts the empty string, and I would like to exclude that.
So I am looking for an $\varepsilon$-free LL(1) grammar $G_1$ that generates $L-\{\varepsilon\}$. I have tried several times without success, leading me to doubt whether $L-\{\varepsilon\}$ is simple deterministic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply start in a slightly different starting state before starting the main recursion:

$$
\begin{array} \\
S & \rightarrow & (EP\\
P & \rightarrow & (EP \\
  & | & \varepsilon \\
E & \rightarrow &iE \\
  & | &sE \\
  & | &nE \\
  & | &(EE \\
  & | &)
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Not monotone due to $P \rightarrow \varepsilon$, but it at least generates $L - \{\varepsilon\}$ (and even contains the original grammar), so a point for that.

Comment: Now that I have researched a bit, the simple deterministic languages contain the languages which have an end marker, which is obviously not the case of this language, so I believe it's highly unlikely it's simple deterministic, making this grammar the best one.